# How does the getAllSynonyms method workd in the rita word net package?

Tags: java, wordnet

Can anyone explain to me how the 'getAllSynonyms' method i have used in the code below works? Every time I run it I get different results. Sometimes the words aren't synonyms at all! What is the significance of the middle argument in the call to the method? Links to any manuals that explain the methods of word net? Apologies if I have violated posting etiquette :).

```
import rita.wordnet.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;
public class Blah 
{


RiWordnet wordnet;

String word;

void setup() 
{

  wordnet = new RiWordnet();
  word = "car";
    String[] poss = wordnet.getPos(word);
    //System.out.println(poss)
    for (int j = 0; j < poss.length; j++) {
        System.out.println("\n\nSynonyms for " + word + " (pos: " + poss[j] + ")");
        String[] synonyms = wordnet.getAllSynonyms(word,poss[0],10);
        Arrays.sort(synonyms);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(synonyms[i]);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Blah b=new Blah();
    b.setup();

}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is here (just click the method names in the right column):

http://www.rednoise.org/rita/wordnet/documentation/

But I have to admit it is not very detailed.

When I run this, I repeatedly get
  poss = [n]
  synonyms = [chip, diode, microchip, thermistor]

If you don't, you may want to check if you have multiple versions of WordNet JARs in your classpath (the word lists are inside the Jar in a folder called `rita/wordnet/wdict.dat`)

You can use `Arrays.toString()` to easily print the contents of an array for debugging, without having to use a `for` loop every time.

The middle argument ('n') in this case is the word class ("a" = adjective, "n" = noun, "r" = adverb, "v" = verb) since some words (like "good") may exist in multiple classes and each of them has individual synonyms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mihi :). But you get same results cause I used a very outlandish word like 'transistor'. if you replace it with something like 'car' the results keep changing !

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh When posting a minimum example, we all would appreciate it if you posted an example that shows the problem. How should we know we should use "car"? You get different examples, since you ask for 10 random synonyms, but there are 92 in WordNet.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of [RiTa](http://www.rednoise.org/rita/), you can call `randomizeResults(false);` to disable this behavior (though you will now need to download WordNet itself separately):

```
import rita.*;
import java.util.*;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  RiWordNet rw = new RiWordNet("/WordNet-3.1"); // point to local installation
  rw.randomizeResults(false);                   // don't randomize results
  String[] s = rw.getAllSynonyms("car", "n");
  System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s));
}
```